# How is heading / windspeed written?

Tags: wind, heading

You have been given wind direction and speed, how would it be expressed?

Thanks

Comment: You need to clarify this, when are you writing it? Who is giving it to you? What do you need it for? Usually when listening to ATIS I write it down like "310 @ 12", or "310 @12G15" if there is a gust, each pilot develops their own short-hand for instructions...

Comment: Dang, really?  This was put on hold in 2 hours, but I think it could be easily edited and answered even if that means giving more information than the asker is seeking.  Metars, TAFs, ATISs, etc. & then there's winds aloft.  Anything missing?

Comment: @RyanMortensen WIthout editing this its impossible to know what the OP was asking, however if you think that you can make a new question with information relevant to the community, by all means make a new question and you can even answer it, its encouraged here.

Comment: @RonBeyer touche` sir!  I didn't look at the edit history.  Someone inferred enough in the first edit to make the actual question appear to be obvious, but looking at the original form this question just needs plain deletion.

Comment: From your original question before the edit, we always express wind direction as where it is coming from.

Comment: Simon answered the original question perfectly. I see no reason for such monumental edits or closing the question.

Comment: @Simon: If this is the actual question (that's not clear to me), then it's [a duplicate](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26549/how-is-wind-direction-reported-blowing-from-or-blowing-to).

Answer (score 3):

[METAR wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/METAR#North_American_METAR_codes) is expressed like this:

**04011KT** indicates the wind is from 040° true (north east) at 11 knots (20 km/h; 13 mph). In the United States, the wind direction must have a 60° or greater variance for variable wind direction to be reported and the wind speed must be greater than 3 knots (5.6 km/h; 3.5 mph).

**04011G20KT** indicates wind gusts reaching 20 knots.

**090V150** indicates the wind direction is varying from 90° true (east) to 150° true (south-southeast).